# Firefox randomly hides everything on the page

Tags: firefox

My firefox randomly hides the DOM or everything on the page for some reason...

Sometimes to a particular websites sometimes it shows the content when I click on a link opens a new window/tab but the original window/tab hides all the content.

What could this be?

Comment: *What* particular websites? And which OS? (And please associate your accounts at http://stackoverflow.com/users/240215?tab=accounts#sort-top so you can edit this question on Super User, to come up with a better title? Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this as well. There are two reasons for this:

1. A bug in firefox. Upgrade to 3.5.7.
2. Windows is running out of memory.

Comment: 1. I did update firefox to 3.5.7;
2. I could have a single tab (not including the opened one).
--- still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turning on Firefox in the safe mode ? See if that makes the problem go away :)